# Normalization of data with different ratings

Tags: normalization

I have a set of data provided by 6 different machines. I want to know which is the most efficient, but each machine has a different power rating, ie. One is 5 kW, while the other is 3kW, and 1.5 kW, with efficiency ratings of 2, 5, and 9 respectively.

I would like to know what method would be applicable to be able to remove this factor and adjust their efficiencies to be comparable, as if the machines all had one similar motor strength. I initially thought of scaling the motors to one motor and using the ratios to scale the efficiency ratings, but it seemed crude. I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terminology to find what method I should use, as my knowledge in statistics is a bit limited.

Thank you!

Comment: This seems like a physics question, not a statistics question.  Recommend posting the question on the Physics site: https://physics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Noted, i'll try posting there. I thought that maybe the values could be adjusted using some form statistical analysis, such as standard score, but I couldn't find how to normalize values in relation to another factor. Thank you!

Comment: You could do that if these were six separate samples of data that were scaled differently, not just simply six different items.

Comment: They do follow a trend, with higher power ratings having lower efficiency. Assuming that the power ratings scale proportionally with the efficiency or that we could find a relationship, would using standard score be possible?

Comment: To get a standard score (z-score) you need a mean of data. So you can calculate a mean of these values, but that won't help you make these values comparable to each other.  Again, not a statistics question.

Comment: noted, thanks. It does seem that an expertise in e-vehicle efficiency and power would really help my question, so I posted this to the physics site. Thank you again for the advice!